# Modify Schema in BigQuery external table (google sheets)

Tags: google-sheets, google-bigquery, database-schema

Last week I created a table in **BigQuery** from **Google Sheets** with a specific schema. Now, I've added two new columns in my Spreadsheet and I'm not able to change the schema in BigQuery. How can I change it?

A couple of months ago it was possible to edit it and add these columns at the end of the table, but right now there's nothing I can do in the UI when I press the 'edit schema' button.

Comment: -Have you tried connecting your [Google Sheet to BigQuery](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/9702507?hl=en), In this way you can update or add columns from the document and the table will be updated.
-You mentioned that previously you could modify it from the UI, but those files were also from GoogleSheet? Or were they another type of files